# Random href ids in Org 9 exported HTML?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

Something seems to have changed in the way HTML is exported from org mode between the 8 and 9 versions.One example, in the Table of Contents, I get entries with anchors like this:

```
a href="#orgfaf035e"
```

while earlier (version 8) I think I was getting

```
a href="#sec.1.1"
```

Those numbers seem to be completely random, so they differ every time I run the exporter again. The result is that if I make a change of one word only in the text, the diff between the new and the old file will be tens of lines of code. This is just noise for someone using a version control system. I wonder if there is an option to return to the old behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is an annoying change in Orgmode...
The only workaround I've found is this hack: https://github.com/alphapapa/unpackaged.el#export-to-html-with-useful-anchors